# How to select rows from array where string contains number in range: MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, indexing

I have this array:

```
AB01    4   7
AB02    3   4
AB02    2   4
AB03    9   5
AB01    3   3
AB04    3   2
AB05    4   1
AB03    4   1
AB05    3   4
AB04    1   5
```

I have 2 number inputs which determine a minimum and maximum value. For example if I set the first input `n1 = 2` and the second input `n2 = 4`, meaning I want the rows which have a value of `AB02`, `AB03` or `AB04` in the first column, I will get output like this:

```
AB02    3   4
AB02    2   4
AB03    9   5
AB04    3   2
AB03    4   1
AB04    1   5
```

I dont know how to create ranging value from `AB02`-`AB04` because it's not a number. I really apreciate your help.

---

Edit: I am trying to use this script, I know my logical indexing isn't right but I am stuck.

```
col1 = 3;
fmt = repmat('%s',1,col1);
enter cofid = fopen('Document2.txt', 'rt');de here
filecolumn = textscan(fid, fmt, 'Delimiter', ' ');
fclose(fid);
FF = horzcat(filecolumn{:});

y1 = input('INPUT1: ')
y = sprintf('AB%.2d',y1)
z1 = input('INPUT2: ')
z = sprintf('AB%.2d',z1)
for o = y:z
   while o == 1 
      index = find(strcmp(FF,o))
   end
   ff = FF(index,:)
end
```

Comment: This question can be split up into different subproblems: 
(1) extract a number from a string
(2) range checking of the elements in an array
(3) logical indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's extract the numbers from the end of the strings in your cell array, you could use regular expressions to keep things general, but I'm going to assume that you always have a 2 digit number at the end of a 4 digit string like you've shown...

```
% Your data
M = {'AB01'  4   7
     'AB02'  3   4
     'AB02'  2   4
     'AB03'  9   5
     'AB01'  3   3
     'AB04'  3   2
     'AB05'  4   1
     'AB03'  4   1
     'AB05'  3   4
     'AB04'  1   5};
% Extracting numbers, using cellfun to operate on each element of the cell array
nums = cellfun(@(r)str2num(r(3:4)), M(:,1));
>> nums = [1
           2
           2
           % ... others ...
           4]
```

Now we can use logical indexing to access the rows you want

```
n1 = 2; % lower bound
n2 = 4; % upper bound
% Create logical array, true where nums is in range [n1,n2], false otherwise    
idx = nums >= n1 & nums <= n2;
```

And retrieve the rows of `M`

```
output = M(idx,:);
>> output = 
   {'AB02'  3  4
    'AB02'  2  4
    'AB03'  9  5
    'AB04'  3  2
    'AB03'  4  1
    'AB04'  1  5}
```

---

For reference, all of the code together without the outputs could look something like this:

```
% Input values
n1 = 2; n2 = 4;
% Your data stored in cell array M, get numbers
nums = cellfun(@(r)str2num(r(3:4)), M(:,1));
% Get rows within range
output = M(nums >= n1 & nums <= n2, :);
```

Comment: `str2num` uses `eval`. Use `str2double` instead

Comment: Event better is to use string and call double on it. x = ones(1000); str = string(x); cll = cellstr(str); tic; double(str); toc; tic; str2double(cll); toc
Elapsed time is 0.534203 seconds.
Elapsed time is 16.009992 seconds.

Comment: @matlabbit I don't have 2016b+ (needed for `string`) to test this, but before that calling `double` on a string of numbers will return an array of their ASCII values... So this recommendation seems iffy

Comment: @Wolfie Calling double on a string is the preferred way to go from string to double. It converts the text representation of a number to the number. Calling double on a character array still gives you ascii values. Also, calling double on a string handles commas as thousands separators more correctly: str2double(",2,,0,") results in 20. double(",2,,0,") results in NaN.

Comment: @Wolfie Additionally (and slightly unrelated), now that you can call string on a double to convert it to a string, you can do "Hello " + 42 which results in "Hello 42". String's plus will do implicit conversions when an appropriate string conversion exists and there are no dispatch precedence issues. No more need for horzcating num2str with string.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a table instead of a cell array and use tableread with TextType string to import the data. Extracting the values is a bit simpler with string (which is available starting in 16b). String is also faster if you're dealing with a large amount of data.

```
lower_bound = 2;
upper_bound = 4;

data = {'AB02'  3  4
        'AB02'  2  4
        'AB03'  9  5
        'AB04'  3  2
        'AB03'  4  1
        'AB04'  1  5};

data = cell2table(data,'VariableNames',{'x','y','z'});
data.x = string(data.x);

value = extractAfter(data.x,2);
value = double(value);

data = data(value >= lower_bound & value <= upper_bound,:)

data =

  6×3 table

      x       y    z
    ______    _    _

    "AB02"    3    4
    "AB02"    2    4
    "AB03"    9    5
    "AB04"    3    2
    "AB03"    4    1
    "AB04"    1    5
```